# Promise A+ Implementation: what to do when call then() and the promise is still pending?

Tags: javascript, promise

I've being working confortably with promise implementations for some time now.

So I've decided to implement my own promise library just for the fun (and learn something in the process too).

I'm trying to follow the [Promise A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) specs (maybe I'll leave some details out, because I'm not meaning to make this a production code).

My full code (still in progress) is in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/hbarcelos/2aa771eafe646b5cd504), but the relevant parts are bellow.

I'm facing a problem implementing `then()`. I simply don't know what to do when the promise is pending:

```
Promise.prototype.then = function(onFulfill, onReject) {
    var ret;
    var self = this;

    if (isFulfilled.call(this)) {
        console.log('fulfilled');
        if (isFunction(onFulfill)) {
            return promiseResolution(this, onFulfill(this.value));
        } else {
            return new Promise(function(resolve){
                resolve(self.value);
            });
        }
    } else if (isRejected.call(this)) {
        console.log('rejected');
        if (isFunction(onReject)) {
            return promiseResolution(this, onReject(this.reason));
        } else {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                reject(self.reason);
            });
        }
    } else if (isPending.call(this)) {
        console.log('pending');
        enqueueCallback(this.fulfillCallbackQueue, onFulfill);
        enqueueCallback(this.rejectCallbackQueue, onReject);
        // ... what now?
    }
};

function promiseResolution(promise, x) {
    if (promise === x) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot resolve promise with itself');
    } else if (x instanceof Promise) {
        if (isFulfilled.call(x)) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                resolve(x.value);
            });
        } else if (isRejected.call(x)) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                reject(x.reason);
            });
        } else {
            return x;
        }
    } else {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            resolve(x);
        });
    }
}
```

The answer must be quite obvious, but I'm kind of mind-blocked here.

### Edit:

I've updated the gist with the test suite I'm writing.

### Edit #2:

I was able to sucessfully run the tests for a first implementation. This is the [git repository](https://github.com/hbarcelos/promise-js) where I've stored my code. I'll try to keep improving it.

Thank's to @BenjaminGruenbaum.

Comment: `... what now?` - no need to do anything until the promise is resolved

Comment: Not exactly. Promise A+ spec states that `then` should always return a promise.

Comment: If you run the last test on my testing script, it will fail with the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - make sure you're not implementing A+ unless you have a very good reason to do just that. It is very tricky to make a good promise implementation.

When the promise is pending - push the following to a handler array:

- the promise you're returning - because Promises A+ requires you detect a promise returning itself and reject on that.
- the reject function for the promise you extract from the constructor.
- the resolve function for the promise you extract from the constructor.
- the onFulfilled handler
- the onRejected handler.

When the promise that returns the new promise undergoes resolution, you need to

- if it rejected - run the rejection handler and `resolve` when it's done (reject if it threw). Check for the same reference on the return value.  If there is no handler or it is not a function - you can pass `e => { throw e; }` instead.
- if it fulfilled - run the fulfillment handler and `resolve` when it's done (reject if it threw). Check for the same reference on the return value. If there is no handler or it is not a function - you can pass `v => v` instead.

Of course, `resolve` itself needs to perform assimilation, as well as from foreign thenables. I recommend running against the promises/A+ test suite and work it out bit by bit until all tests pass.

Comment: That's a good start, I'll try to implement it and come back here if further questions pop up. Thank you :)

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos just remember that further questions belong in a new question on StackOverflow - feel free to ping me here if you'd like me to take a look and good luck. I assume you've already read "Promises/A+ understanding the spec through implementation" but if you have not it's a good read up to get you up to speed.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I meant further questions about your suggestion, not the implementation itself. I had this article in my TO READ, thank's for remembering me that.